# Android project builds fine using Ant but gives runtime error

Tags: android, ant

I am using ANT to build android project ,I am adding external jar in the lib folder and trying to build the project it builds perfectly but i am getting run time error ...i have seen some groups they have said that the build.xml has to be modified with these changes

```
<target name="dex" depends="compile"> 
    <exec executable="${dx}" failonerror="true"> 
        <arg value="-JXmx384M" /> 
        <arg value="--dex" /> 
        <arg value="--output=${basedir}/${intermediate-dex}" /> 
        <arg value="--locals=full" /> 
        <arg value="--positions=lines" /> 
        <arg path="${basedir}/${outdir-classes}" /> 
    </exec> 
</target>
```

Add a new arg after the last one:

but when i add the same it is not building does any body have occured with the same problem ......
and the error is no command specified

Comment: how about posting your build.xml and the error?

Comment: I have posted the xml contents which i have added extra in the build.xml i want to add an external jar file in which i am unable to compile even using ant . I want to use that jar is there any other way to do that ? plz help

Comment: What is the runtime error you mention?

Answer (score -1):

> trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class":
>   [2009-05-11 09:24:13 - ChitMeAndroidClient] 
>   Attempt to include a core VM class in something other than a core library.

It is likely that you have attempted to include the core library from a desktop
virtual machine into an application, which will most assuredly not work. If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine binary, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the `--core-library` option to suppress this error message. If you go ahead and use `--core-library` but are in fact building an application, then please be aware that your build will still fail at some point; you will simply be denied the pleasure of reading this helpful error message.

this is the compile time error.......